# Spring-boot default EntityManager

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

Does spring-boot have a default EntityManager. I am setting one up right now but I noticed when my project loads I see this:

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

Is this a default EntityManager and if so, how do I access it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just `@Autowire` it in your class

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@PersistenceContext` annotation to inject the entity manager into your spring beans:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, all you need to do is configure the data source using the `spring.datasource.{url, username, password, driver-class-name}` properties in `application.properties`.

If you want to use an in-memory database like H2 for development, not even that is necessary. Just include the database as a dependency.

Once you do that, you should be able to inject the `EntityManager` into your beans.